# How to setup two different process functions for single flink job config?

Tags: kotlin, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

I have a single flink job with 3 different inputs (optional) and the same output will be emitted for each type of input.

input1 uses `KeyedProcessFunction()`
input2 uses `ProcessWindowFuction()`

Basically, the job input is a union of three inputs and single output.
How do we configure the flink job so that for single job, I can use above both the process functions.

I wanted to use `KeyedProcessFunction()` for `input1` and `ProcessWindowFuction()` for `input2`.

below code is for `input2` only, If I want to use `input1` i have to use `.process(processFuction())` instead of `.process(MyProcessWindowFunction())` in the job config, how do we configure so that I can use both the functions in single job ?

```
    fun setupJob(env: StreamExecutionEnvironment) {

        val testStream = env.sampleStream()
                   .keyBy { it.f0 }
                   .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(10)))
                   .process(MyProcessWindowFunction())
    
            testStream.map { it.toKafkaMessage() }
                    .kafkaSink<SampleOutput>() }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single Flink job can contain several pipelines. E.g.,

```java
env.fromSource(input1)
  .keyBy(...)
  .process(new MyKeyedProcessFunction())
  .sinkTo(sink1)

env.fromSource(input2)
  .keyBy(...)
  .window(...)
  .process(new MyProcessWindowFunction())
  .sinkTo(sink2)

env.execute()
```